# Anaconda Python

Tags: command-line, anaconda

Hello I just wanted to ask that when I use my terminal to download anaconda python on the last step it automatically says no. Can anyone tell me what to do:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please do not have pictures of text include all text in the body of the question.

Comment: No idea.  My guess is when it was performing the installation, you were impatient and had hit the "Enter" key.  Then, when the prompt came back, it accepted the "Enter" key that you had pressed earlier.  Either that, or your keyboard's "Enter" key is stuck and when you hit it once, the computer is registering it twice or something like that.  These are my guesses...

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of trouble with anaconda too.

In case you are just interested in Spyder, I recommend:

```
sudo apt install spyder3
```